# Inserting into database SQL using c++

Tags: c++, sql, database

I'm fairly  new to SQL and C++ , I am trying to write a C++ function to insert information into mySQL.

```
void insertEmployee(MYSQL* conn, struct Employee emp) {

    if ((findEmployeee(conn, this->employeeNumber, emp)) {

        cout << "An employee with the same employee number exists." << endl;
        menu();


    }
    else {

        string query ="INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(" + emp.lastname + emp.firstName + emp.email + emp.phone + emp.extension + "1004" + emp.jobTitle +emp.officeCode +")"+ "WHERE employeeNumber = " +emp.employeeNumber;
        cout << "The new employee is added successfully.";
    }


}
```

How can I achieve a insert command through C++ , also what are some good resources I can look at for help, everything I came across is very overwhelming.

Here is the question I am trying to do
void insertEmployee(MYSQL *conn,  struct Employee emp);

This function receives a MYSQL pointer (a reference variable to a MySQL database) and a 
structure of type Employee and inserts the given employee information stored in the 
parameter emp to employee table.
In function insertEmployee(), call the function findEmployee() to see if the employee number 
of the given employee exists. If an employee with the same employee number exists display a 
proper message:
“An employee with the same employee number exists.” and return to the menu.
Otherwise, insert the employee information into the employee table and display the following 
message: 
“The new employee is added successfully.”

Comment: This is not the correct syntax and using concatenation is completely reckless. **Use prepared statements with placeholder values**.

Comment: See `std::ostringstream` for creating strings using values.

Comment: any good resources I should look into?